# How do decompose this relation from 3NF to BCNF?

Tags: database-theory

Given a relation with attributes { A, X, Y, Z } and functional dependencies $AX\rightarrow Y, AX\rightarrow Y, Y\rightarrow A, Z\rightarrow B$, I would think that this would be in 3NF because there are no partial or transitive dependencies. What I don't understand is how to decompose the relation to BCNF by ensuring no relation has a determinant that is not a candidate key.

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state an exercise-style problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the exact problem you happen to be working on.